# Nested CANVAS elements

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a  element within another  element? I know i can layer them, but is this possible -

```
<canvas id="parent">
    <canvas id="child"></canvas>
</canvas>
```

I tried but doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 19):

The [canvas specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html) does not allow for this. The canvas element may be used in an embedded content context; nesting a canvas element places it in a fallback content context, which is not supported.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to handle background and foreground separately, you could use two canvas and put one above the other with css.

```
<canvas id="bg" width="640" height="480" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0">
</canvas>
<canvas id="fg" width="640" height="480" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1">
</canvas>
```

Actually this one of the tips to improve canvas performance. Source: [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider doing a virtual embedding by translating to various positions on your canvas.

Here's an example of doing this:

http://marketimpacts.com/storage/9781118385357%20ls0702%20Complex%20Objects.htm

It's from:

[http://www.amazon.com/HTML5-Canvas-For-Dummies-Cowan/dp/1118385357/ref=cm_cmu_up_thanks_hdr](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118385357)

Comment: To see the code, right click on the example web page and select View Page Source.

Answer (score -1):

You can, as Isaac Zepeda said in his answer, you need to have different canvas id's and z indexes. You also need to name almost all of the variables and functions for each canvas something different so that you don't draw on canvas A when you mean to draw on canvas B.